# Possible Conference Speaking Sponsorships -- 2011

Tags: discussion

We're evaluating the feasibility of **sponsoring a member of the GIS community to speak at a conference in 2011**.

Speaking is a relatively big "ask", so this needs to be planned many months in advance. Let's get started!

We'd like the community to establish **where** ...

> What relevant programming conferences are coming up in 2011 that have open speaker slots or calls for papers?

... and then **who**.

> Which members of the GIS community are strongly interested in being sponsored by Stack Exchange, Inc to speak at one of the above conferences in 2011?

To be clear, the speaker is free talk about anything he or she wants so long as it would be roughly on topic for this site -- with a quick acknowledgement of support from Stack Exchange and a mention of the community here.

Answer (score 11):

I'll leave the where aside for the moment, but my first nomination for who is Bill Huber ([@whuber](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/664/whuber)).

Bill is demonstrably expert, able to communicate well, and has a long history of positive involvement in a number GIS forae. He consistently supports those new to our community with a sensitivity I try to emulate.

Comment: the sensitivity I have a hope of achieving, the expertise, well, maybe after another decade or so ;-)

Comment: I strongly support nominating Bill.

Comment: +1 I think Bill would do a great job.  He's the best at Where types of questions, so if he's game, maybe he should answer the Where part.

Comment: definitely +1 for Bill.

Answer (score 5):

On the academic side, there are a few upcoming conferences that might be relevant:

- [FOSS4G 2011](http://2011.foss4g.org/) would be excellent, though it looks like the presentation deadline has passed
- [GIS in the Rockies](http://www.gisintherockies.org/GISITR2011/About/About.aspx) is probably a mixture of practitioners and developers
- [ACM sigspatial](http://acmgis2011.cs.umn.edu/) should be deeply technical

Many programmer-centric conferences will also have tracks relating to the issues of GIS, but there are surprisingly few conferences targeted directly at geospatial software developers.

Comment: +1 The interesting thing about the academic conferences is that with a little reading between the lines and extrapolation you often can see what capabilities will be commonplace 5-15 years in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I've never attended, but I've always been impressed by the caliber of [AutoCarto](http://www.cartogis.org/autocarto.php)'s proceedings.  Anyone know when the next one will be held?

Comment: +1 That looks interesting, but the Web page is not current :-(.

Answer (score 2):

For the German-speaking community, [AGIT](http://www.agit.at) (biggest Austrian conference with many visitors from Germany) and [FOSSGIS](http://www.fossgis.de/konferenz/2011/) (German open source GIS conference with big OSM section) would be of interest. But it's a little late for those two events as FOSSGIS2011 is already over and AGIT call for papers is closed too.